# Evaluating formula in office-js Excel addin

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to evaluate a formula in Excel-online addin that will be provided by a user.

VSTO has [Application.Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel) method to which I can provide any formula.

I've noticed that office-js has [Worksheet functions](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/functions.md#list) but they need to be defined compile-time and what I am having is a string formula.

Is there a way to evaluate string formula like in VSTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not possible to do today, please upvote in our uservoice channel.